# How to get the current location in Google Maps Android API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

Using

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)
```

can set the myLocation layer enable.
But the problem is how to get the myLocation when the user clicks on the button?
I want to get the longitude and latitude.

Comment: what you need ? need the location when user touches the screen or need the user location when when user click on button like "Get My Location" ?

Comment: *Check this latest one getting current location*
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56110319/5628693

Comment: [This is working correctly latest one ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56110319/5628693)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The Google Maps API location now works, even has listeners, you can do it using that, for example:

```
private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
        if(mMap != null){
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));
        }
    }
};
```

and then set the listener for the map:

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
```

This will get called when the map first finds the location.

No need for LocationService or LocationManager at all.

> `OnMyLocationChangeListener` interface is deprecated.
>   use com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi instead. FusedLocationProviderApi provides improved location finding and power usage and is used by the "My Location" blue dot. See the MyLocationDemoActivity in the sample applications folder for example example code, or the Location Developer Guide.

Comment: good solution but you should add remove location marker before adding new one. On every location change, google map will add new marker

Comment: it works now, but the problem is there is some delay.

Comment: "This interface is deprecated.
use com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi instead" https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener

Answer (score 31):

At the moment GoogleMap.getMyLocation() always returns null under every circumstance.

There are currently two bug reports towards Google, that I know of, [Issue 40932](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40932#) and [Issue 4644](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4644).

Implementing a LocationListener as brought up earlier would be incorrect because the LocationListener would be out of sync with the LocationOverlay within the new API that you are trying to use.

Following the tutorial on Vogella's Site, linked earlier by Pramod J George, would give you directions for the Older Google Maps API.

So I apologize for not giving you a method to retrieve your location by that means.  For now the locationListener may be the only means to do it, but I'm sure Google is working on fixing the issue within the new API.

Also sorry for not posting more links, StackOverlow thinks I'm spam because I have no rep.

---- Update on February 4th, 2013 ----

Google has stated that the issue will be fixed in the next update to the Google Maps API via  [Issue 4644](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4644).  I am not sure when the update will occur, but once it does I will edit this post again.

---- Update on April 10th, 2013 ----

Google has stated the issue has been fixed via  [Issue 4644](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4644).  It should work now.

Comment: The linked thread has a post that says this has been fixed. You might want to update your answer. +1

Comment: I seem to still be getting `null`.  I call `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` in `onCreate`, then try to `getMyLocation()` in `onPostCreate`.

Comment: I got null even in onPostCreate method

Comment: @mattblang I tryed what you said but I still getting `null` in `onPostCreate` method

Comment: @PavelRyzhov Yeah, I think I meant that I still was getting `null` when trying the call in `onPostCreate`.  The problem is probably that a location hasn't been acquired yet, since that happens asynchronously and can take some time, particularly with GPS.

Answer (score 19):

try this

```
LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
```

Comment: getLastKnownLocation can return null, so it is not reliable enough

Comment: This is for get LAst Known Location, but not te current location.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that you have turned ON the location services on the device.
Else you won't get any location related info.

This works for me,

```
    map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange (Location location) {
           LatLng loc = new LatLng (location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
           map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));
        }
    };
    map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

To get the location when the user clicks on a button call this method in the onClick-

```
void getCurrentLocation() {
    Location myLocation  = mMap.getMyLocation();
    if(myLocation!=null)
    {
        double dLatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double dLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
        Log.i("APPLICATION"," : "+dLatitude);
        Log.i("APPLICATION"," : "+dLongitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude)).title("My Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Utils.getBitmap("pointer_icon.png"))));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude), 8));

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to fetch the current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Also make sure that the

> setMyLocationEnabled

is set to **true**.

Try and see if this works...

Comment: Mylocation is always null

Comment: mMap.getMyLocation() is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`GoogleMap.getMyLocation()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#getMyLocation%28%29)?

Comment: That unfortunately won't inform you of updates. Reportedly it's broken, too.

Comment: **Update:** "This method is deprecated.
use com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient instead" https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location , http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Answer (score 1):

I just found this code snippet simple and functional,
try :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
...
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
}}
```

here's the link of the tutorial : [Getting the Last Known Location](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
} else {
    // Show rationale and request permission.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

 @Override

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
{

loc.getLatitude();

loc.getLongitude();

String Text = “My current location is: ” +

“Latitud = ” + loc.getLatitude() +

“Longitud = ” + loc.getLongitude();

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),Text,   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



tvlat.setText(“”+loc.getLatitude());

tvlong.setText(“”+loc.getLongitude());

this.gpsCurrentLocation();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will give the current location.

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
Location userLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();
        LatLng myLocation = null;
        if (userLocation != null) {
            myLocation = new LatLng(userLocation.getLatitude(),
                    userLocation.getLongitude());
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLocation,
                    mMap.getMaxZoomLevel()-5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one condition, I tested that it wasn't null was, if you allow enough time to user to touch the "get my location" layer button, then it will not get null value.

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer works but some of the used methods are now deprecated so I think it is best if I answer this question with updated methods.

this is answer is completely from [this guide on google developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/current-place-tutorial#get-the-location-of-the-android-device-and-position-the-map)

so here is step by step guide:

1. implement all this in your map activity

   `MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`
2. in your `onCreate`:

   ```
   private GoogleMap mMap;
   private Context context;
   private TextView txtStartPoint,txtEndPoint;
   private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
   private Location mLastKnownLocation;
   private LatLng mDefaultLocation;
   private CameraPosition mCameraPosition;
   private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
   context = this;
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
           .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                   this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
           .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
           .addApi(LocationServices.API)
           .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
           .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
           .build();
   mGoogleApiClient.connect();
   }
   ```
3. in your `onConnected` :

   ```
   SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)     getSupportFragmentManager()
           .findFragmentById(map);
   mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
   ```
4. in your `onMapReady` :

   ```
   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
   mMap = googleMap;

   // Do other setup activities here too, as described elsewhere in this tutorial.

   // Turn on the My Location layer and the related control on the map.
   updateLocationUI();

   // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.
   getDeviceLocation();
   }
   ```
5. and these two are methods in `onMapReady` :

   ```
   private void updateLocationUI() {
     if (mMap == null) {
       return;
   }

   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
           android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
           == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
   }

   if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
       mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
       mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
   } else {
       mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
       mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
       mLastKnownLocation = null;
   }
   }

   private void getDeviceLocation() {
   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
           android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
           == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
   }

   if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
       mLastKnownLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
               .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
   }

   // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
   float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
   if (mCameraPosition != null) {
       mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(mCameraPosition));
   } else if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {
       mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
               new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                       mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
   } else {
       Log.d("pouya", "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
       mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
       mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
   }
   }
   ```

this is very fast , smooth and effective. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use `FusedLocationApi` since `OnMyLocationChangeListener` is deprecated.

First declare these 3 variables:

```
private LocationRequest  mLocationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient  mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationListener mLocationListener;
```

Define methods:

```
private void initGoogleApiClient(Context context)
{
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context).addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks()
    {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
        {
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);

            setLocationListener();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
        {
            Log.i("LOG_TAG", "onConnectionSuspended");
        }
    }).build();

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

private void setLocationListener()
{
    mLocationListener = new LocationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            String lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            String lon = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            Log.i("LOG_TAG", "Latitude = " + lat + " Longitude = " + lon);
        }
    };

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mLocationListener);
}

private void removeLocationListener()
{
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationListener);
}
```

- `initGoogleApiClient()` is used to initialize `GoogleApiClient` object
- `setLocationListener()` is used to setup location change listener
- `removeLocationListener()` is used to remove the listener

Call `initGoogleApiClient` method to start the code working :)  Don't forget to remove the listener (`mLocationListener`) at the end to avoid memory leak issues.