# How do I add a marker to my current location in my app?

Tags: android, dictionary

How can I add a custom marker to my current location in my map?
At this stage no marker is being displayed at my location.

I'm using Google map api v2 and android version 4.0.4.

Comment: Do u have changed the location and verified that marker is changed to that location?? Post some code/logcat/give correct information that what you have tried????

Comment: To find current location refer this... http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/ and to add overlay refer this... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: hi refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844209/google-maps-android-api-v2-and-current-location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the latitude and longitude for the current location is lat and lng.(Which you can find out programatically).

```
 GoogleMap mMap;
 // Initialize your map ...And
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(lat , lng)).title("Marker"));
```

Use **icon()** method for image .

Comment: Whats this??? You have hard-coded Lat/Long details to get the current location....

Comment: What is `GoogleMap`? is this code for android-java-sdk?

Comment: hi guys, Ive gotten the app to display current location. On the location i small blue dot appears now with a light blue shade around it. I think il stick with this.

Comment: @Aʌɐpɥɐuı : Yes. Now replaced with lat and lng. Also the Op wanted to ask about the marker.

Comment: @ Adil Soomro : Yes . You can refer this - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/