# How to show current location on map using API V2 in android

Tags: android

I want to show my current location with pin point on map. I want to use API v2 but I dont know how to use this api v2 and how to implement it.

Comment: have a look at this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844209/google-maps-android-api-v2-and-current-location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please have a look at this sample.

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Location

And also have a look at this google map sdk with sample 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code

Hope this will help you.

Comment: is that google map that require an internet connection @itsrajesh4uguys... or is it an another sdk (library) that can use offline map embedded into the device?