# Custom Info Window Adapter and 2 other issues

Tags: android, google-maps

So  i was searching for a solution and bumped into [the code from this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17969929/2389512)

I am getting error here:

`googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(
                GPSTracker.this));` saying that cannot be resolved to a type.

also `Share` cannot be resolved to a variable

```
private void GetCurrentLocation() {

    double[] d = getlocation();
    Share.lat = d[0];
    Share.lng = d[1];

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Share.lat, Share.lng)).title("Current Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.red)));
```

I couldn't get any solution for `CustomInfoWindowAdapter` and i do not understand what does `Share` stands for.

Any help in understanding and solving my issue would be very much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro

[custom info window adapter with custom data in map v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090148/custom-info-window-adapter-with-custom-data-in-map-v2)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I did everything that is written there now, the problem still wasnt solved.