# Google Now Homelocation

Tags: android, google-maps, google-now

In my application I have a button, to show the user his way to go, on a Google Maps view.

Is there a way to get the Home-/Work location of the user from Google Now?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Google Maps API in your application and find out your location through existing methods like this

```
LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
```

credits : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14493351/2071742

Comment: I dont want the current location. I want the HOME-Location that google-now figures out after a while.