# Google maps mark (current location) crashes the application, how to fix it?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation

I am trying to add current location mark to my android Google map application in Android Studio.

My code:

```
private void setUpMap() {
Location location = null;
LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
Marker marker;
marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng((location.getLatitude()), location.getLongitude())).title("Marker"));}
```

It causes my application to crash. Underneath there are mistakes that appeared while running my application:

http://postimg.org/image/qrxdo9dl5/full/

(I used postimage to upload a larger size screen-shot)

---

Before I modified my code, I had a working code set to position 0,0:

```
private void setUpMap() {
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
```

Then I tried to change location '0,0' to read current latitude and longitude and show it on my Google map. I changed my code based on this post: [How to get the current location in Google Maps Android API v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756261/how-to-get-the-current-location-in-google-maps-android-api-v2)

I am a java beginner and any help is much appreciated. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: How do you plan on getting a valid `Location` Object?  Currently you just declare `location` and set it to `null`, hence the `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullPointerException because your Location object is set to **null**. In the linked answer the location object comes from the location callback.

```
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) // location object here
```

You can easily get the Location from your map reference like so

```
Location location = mMap.getMyLocation();
```

However this method is deprecated and using the location API is encouraged. To get location from the API you can follow this guide:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

You build a GoogleApiClient, connect it, and then use it to get a location.

```
Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```