# Calculating the Distance between "setMyLocationEnabled" and a marker set on the google map

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make an application on Android which allows me to see the distance between two points on google maps, the distance points being The location i am currently at and the other point being a marker on the google maps.

I have managed to set where I am on the map using `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` and i want to then be able to compare it to a marker i have on the google map which is

```
map.addMarker(newMarkerOptions().position(LOCATION_BEIJING).title("Find me here!"));
```

Comment: Are you using javascript like the tag suggests?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Location` class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html).
First set the marker location:

```
Location markerLoc = new Location("Marker");
markerLoc.setLatitude(marker.latitude);
markerLoc.setLongitude(marker.longitude);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13756261/3879470) to get the current Location using `OnMyLocationChangeListener` and set your Current Location:

```
Location currentLoc = new Location("Current");
currentLoc.setLatitude(location.latitude);
currentLoc.setLongitude(location.longitude);
```

Then you can use the `Location` class' `distanceTo` method to get the distance in meters like this:

```
Float distance = currentLoc.distanceTo(markerLoc);
```