# How to get current location of device on google maps api v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I´ve found some methods to do that but are deprecated or doesn´t work. I would like to get current latitude and longitude from device.

Here is how I'm getting the current location, but the GoogleMap `getMyLocation()` method [is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMyLocation()):

```
void getCurrentLocation()
{
    Location myLocation  = map.getMyLocation();
    if(myLocation!=null)
    {
        double dLatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double dLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude))
                .title("My Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude), 8));

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to fetch the current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code/work before asking someone else to write it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519198/how-to-get-the-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-android

Hope this link helps you.

Comment: Using that GPSTracker class is not recommended, see here: http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**For targeting api-23 and higher:**

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582595/4409409).

**For targeting api-22 and lower:**

It's actually quite simple, using the FusedLocationProviderAPI is recommended over using the older open source Location APIs, especially since you're already using a Google Map so you are already using Google Play Services.

Simply set up a Location Listener, and update your current location Marker in each `onLocationChanged()` callback.  If you only want one location update, just un-register for callbacks after the first callback returns.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private Marker marker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){

            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        }

        if (map == null) {
            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap retMap) {

        map = retMap;

        setUpMap();

    }

    public void setUpMap(){

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;

        //remove previous current location Marker
        if (marker != null){
            marker.remove();
        }

        double dLatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double dLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude))
                .title("My Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude), 8));

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for response until now. I tried this code but I don´t know where is called the listener onLocationChanged because it doesn´t work. It suppose is called automaticly, isn´t it?

Comment: Im trying in my device.

Comment: @ReneLimon Sorry about that, there was an error in the code and it wasn't building the GoogleApiClient.  I just updated the answer with fully tested and working code!

Comment: @DanielNugent java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {akashdubey.com.googlemapsdemo/akashdubey.com.googlemapsdemo.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference

Comment: @akash make sure you have the map in your layout xml, see the answer here for updated code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-show-current-location-on-a-google-map-on-android-marshmallow/34582595#34582595

Answer (score 2):

*This is working correctly remaining all are deprecated*

```
   private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
 fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    Activity#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
    }
    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        mylatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        mylongitude = location.getLongitude();
                        Log.d("chk", "onSuccess: "+mylongitude);
                        // Logic to handle location object
                    }
                }
            });
```

[This link will be helpful](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#GetLocation)

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, LocationListener,
    View.OnClickListener {


private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";
Location mCurrentLocation;
String mLastUpdateTime;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private ArrayList<LatLng> routePoints;
private Polyline line;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);


    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //Initializing googleApiClient
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    routePoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F); //added
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //changed
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
    // mMap.clear();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onMarkerClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onMarkerDragStart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onMarkerDrag", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    // getting the Co-ordinates
   /* latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
    longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;*/

    //move to current position
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    // googleMapOptions.mapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID)
    //    .compassEnabled(true);

   /* LatLng india = new LatLng(20.5937, 78.9629);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(india).title("Marker in India"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(india));
    mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);*/
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    googleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    addMarker();
   /* //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));

    PolylineOptions pOptions = new PolylineOptions()
            .width(5)
            .color(Color.GREEN)
            .geodesic(true);
    for (int z = 0; z < routePoints.size(); z++) {
        LatLng point = routePoints.get(z);
        pOptions.add(point);
    }
    line = mMap.addPolyline(pOptions);
    routePoints.add(latLng);*/
}

private void addMarker() {
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(this);
    iconFactory.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_GREEN);
    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon(mLastUpdateTime)));
    options.anchor(iconFactory.getAnchorU(), iconFactory.getAnchorV());
    LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    options.position(currentLatLng);
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(options);
    long atTime = mCurrentLocation.getTime();
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date(atTime));
    mCurrLocationMarker.setTitle(mLastUpdateTime);
    Log.d(TAG, "Marker added.............................");
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng,
            18));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));
    PolylineOptions pOptions = new PolylineOptions()
            .width(5)
            .color(Color.BLACK)
            .geodesic(true);
    for (int z = 0; z < routePoints.size(); z++) {
        LatLng point = routePoints.get(z);
        pOptions.add(point);
    }
    line = mMap.addPolyline(pOptions);
    routePoints.add(currentLatLng);
    Log.d(TAG, "Zoom done.............................");
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. You have posted a wall of code. Don't you think it would be better with some description?